# Delete GridView Rows in button cick without RowDeleting that not saved in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a gridview,

1. When Button ADD is clicked the textboxs values will be  added to gridview.
2. After adding values to gridview i want to select a row and click delete button but error occurs to me on deleting.

**My GridView Code**

```
<asp:GridView ClientIDMode="Static" ID="GridPesonal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Class="GrdSty" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="RowNumber">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="ردیف">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="از تاریخ"> 
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="تا تاریخ">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SherkatName" HeaderText="نام شرکت،سازمان یا موسسه" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkUnitName" HeaderText="واحد محل کار"> 
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sharh" HeaderText="شرح دقیق شغل/سمت/مسئولیت" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkTime" HeaderText="زمان کار" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="توضیحات">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SavabegSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="SavabegSelect_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        موردی ثبت نشده است.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Btn Delete Code**

```
<asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="BtnDelete" CssClass="btnregister"  runat="server" Text="حذف" OnClick="BtnDelete_Click"  />
```

**Code behind of btn Delete**

```
protected void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridPesonal.Rows)
     {
         CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("SavabegSelect");
          if (chkdelete.Checked)
          {
              GridPesonal.DeleteRow(gvrow.RowIndex);
          }

   } 
 }
```

When execute above code this error show

```
The GridView 'GridPesonal' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.
```

Comment: where is the delete button? I have also remove irreverent code.

Comment: you want delete a particular row, i mean the selected row right??

Answer (score 0):

Have you used command-name as `Delete` on `BtnDelete`.
Remove that from `Delete Button` it will work.

Comment: <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="BtnDelete" CssClass="btnregister" runat="server" Text="حذف"
                                                                           OnClick="BtnDelete_Click"  />

Comment: can you put gridview html in the question

Comment: I dont want use rowdeleting event but this says use event rowdeleting event

Comment: @user849657 Update you question and put html of griview in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRoute" DataKeyNames="Route" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                           AllowPaging="true" Width="30%" 
                          onrowdeleting="gvRoute_RowDeleting">
```

---

Remove `onrowdeleting="gvRoute_RowDeleting`

or wirte event for

```
protected void gvRoute_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
          \\
         }
```

or Use the `"CommandName"` property `"Delete"`

Or Use `OnClick`

```
<asp:GridView ClientIDMode="Static" ID="GridPesonal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Class="GrdSty" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="RowNumber" OnClick="BtnDelete">
```

Comment: This error says that i shoud use rowdeleting when use deleterow